# How to group List of Object by date?

Tags: java, collections, grouping

My Class:

```
public class Proposal {
  Date createDate;
  // ...
}
```

We have two objects `java.util.Date` and know for sure that the objects of this collection are between these two dates. How to divide these objects by day between these dates, so that I can get a list of these objects by date?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
public Map<String, Set<Proposal>> groupProposals(Iterable<Proposal> proposals) {
    Map<String, Set<Proposal>> map = new HashMap<>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    for (Proposal p : proposals) {
        String key = sdf.format(p.getCreateDate());
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, new HashSet<>());
        }
        map.get(key).add(p);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: working with streams and mapping lately can remove For loop and just return `proposals.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->sdf.format(p.getCreateDate()),Collectors.mapping(i-> i, Collectors.toSet())));`

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 8 this can be accomplished seamlessly with [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<Date, List<Proposal>> groupedByDate = proposals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Proposal::getDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to get one of the lists. `List<Object> inDateList = list.stream().filter(o-> startDate< o.createDate && o.createDate< endDate).collect(Collectors.toList());`

then `List<Object> outDateList = new ArrayList<>(list); outDateList.removeAll(inDateList);`

*EDIT*
Just to clarify on my note above.

```
public Map<String, Set<Proposal>> groupProposals(Iterable<Proposal> proposals) {
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
return proposals.stream()
//GroupingBy creates the Map<Key, Collection<Something>>
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->sdf.format(p.getCreateDate()),//Creates the Key and buckets
        Collectors.mapping(i-> i, Collectors.toSet()))); //what kind of buckets do you want. 
}
```

Comment: You did not understand. I need to break this list by day. Suppose date1 = 01/01/2010; date2 = 01/01/2011. I need to divide this list into 365 (days).